# using ErrorT transformer monad in do section

Tags: haskell, error-handling, monads

I would like to understand how to deal with stack of transformators in do section.  It is also about error handling.

Namely, I will show you my problem in my case.
I have some funcion:

```
foo :: Int -> String -> IO (Either String (Value, Integer))
```

Body of `foo` is not important here.

```
ef :: evalExpr :: Int -> String ->  IO (Either String (Value, Integer))
```

Now,

```
f :: Integer -> String -> StateT Integer (ReaderT Integer (ErrorT String IO)) ()
f i s = do
  vl <- lift $ lift $ lift $ ef i s
  ....
  return ()
```

`ef` can call throwError. Also it can return `(Value, String)`.
I would like to be able (`....`)  do something with Right value (so `(Value, String)`).  However, I can't do it. It is my permanent problem.

Idea is following:
When `ef` called `throwError` then  `foo` should propagate the same error (so `Left String`). Neverhteless, when `ef` return `Right Value (so (Value, String))` I would like to use it and on this base make decision what should return `foo` - `throwError` or `(Value, ())`

I know about `fmap` and `<*>`.
Can you help me, please ?

Comment: I can remember your question from earlier but I have trouble seen how your parts are related there - (for example you don't seem to use `foo` in `f`) - can you please produce a working example (obviously it may have compile errors - but it should be complete in the sense that things like `...` are not present) and the error your get?

Comment: btw: this time you probably want to wrap `ef` into `ErrorT` (`vl <- lift $ lift $ ErrorT $ ef i s`

Comment: "ef can call throwError. Also it can return (Value, String).". No. And No. Please review the description, because it's hard to follow otherwise

Comment: What is the trailing `()` in your return value for `f`? `StateT` only takes two types, the state type (`Integer`) and the underlying monad `(ReaderT Integer (ErrorT String IO))`.

Comment: The semantics you are describing are precisely that of `>>=`. Monadic bind in the `ErrorT` monad propagates the error if it occurs, or allows you to access the value that was produced by the computation otherwise. It seems like you already have everything you need - just use the result `vl` after the line `vl <- lift $ lift $ lift $ ef i s`.

Answer (score 2):

The function:

```
ef :: Int -> String ->  IO (Either String (Value, Integer))
```

Can only `throwError` an `IOException`:

```
instance MonadError IOException IO where
    throwError = ioError
    catchError = catch
```

Otherwise, it's just an `IO` function returning `Either String (Value, Integer)`.

Given that function, to act on its value you need to execute it in an `IO`-capable context, and then simply use the resulting value:

```
callEf :: IO ()
callEf = do
    result <- ef ...
    case result of
        Left s ->         -- do something with the String
        Right (v, i) ->   -- do something with the tuple

    return ()
    -- ^ you can also obviously produce the value above,
    -- if you want something more complicated than ()
```

This doesn't change if you're in a monad stack. In your function `f`, calling `lift` three times give you an `IO` context. After that, you can do whatever you want with the resulting value, including any operation from the stack, like `throwError` (after two lifts) or `put` (with no lifts).

Alternatively, refer to my answer to your previous question to get rid of the `lift`s.

If you want the error propagation to happen automatically from `Either` to `ErrorT`, it would be reasonably simple, just like above:

```
eitherToError :: Either e v -> ErrorT e m v
eitherToError f = case f of
    Left err -> throwError err
    Right val -> return val
```

Which you can [easily search for in Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=Either+e+v+-%3E+ErrorT+e+m+v), resulting [in a very similar implementation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/GenI-0.24.3/docs/src/NLP-GenI-ErrorIO.html#liftEither) in some library.

---

All that being said, it seems that `ErrorT` is deprecated in favor of `Control.Monad.Trans.Except`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Don't think about my problem. Is there no other solution ? Maybe applicative ? I would like to be able propagate error if it happened before, could you explain this issue. I ask for it, becaue I am aware that my first post was unclear. It is why I would like to your personally  answer - to be more precisely - handling error (propagation also!) with my monad. Could you edit your answer, please ?